# How to get JSON object by Query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, get

I have to work with queries like:
Controller/Action?query ={"action":"test","id":"13037313353","pin":"452312"}
by GET.

My ViewModel:

```
 public class ValidatePinViewModel
    {
        public ActionType action { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Pin { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
 public JsonResult ValidateVisit(CommonViewModel model)
        {
            //model is null          

            return Json(new InvalidPin());
        }
```

Now I got null for my view. How I can get the correct model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could add a string to get object.

Something like:

```
 public JsonResult ValidateVisit(string query)
 {
    ValidatePinViewModel model = Json.Deserialize<ValidatePinViewModel>(query);       
    return Json(new InvalidPin());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As there is very little supportive information on this question, I'm going to take a shot and say that you're not `POSTING` to an action. e.g.

```
[HttpPost] // <-- Make sure you define your POST action
public JsonResult ValidateVisit(CommonViewModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

A *GET*, as you speficy in your tags, is not going to post a model. Unless you are specifically denoting it both in where you define your form element as well as on the action itself, it will be null.

Comment: Yep, I am working with another service, which send this type of query by GET.

Comment: Then the other service is wrong.  If the other service is posting data, it should use POST.

Comment: I know. I can`t change it. I can only use it.